# Are there security rist if my okta credentials are exposed in frontend?

Tags: javascript, okta, okta-api

I am trying to implement Okta in my app. All tutorials I saw online (even on the docs) has the config in the front-end. Sample config below:

```js
const oktaConfig = {
  issuer: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OKTA_ISSUER,
  clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
  responseMode: 'query',
  response_type: 'code',
  tokenManager: {
    storage: 'sessionStorage',
  },
};
```

This can be viewed by the user in their browser. I was wondering if this has any security issues? This is how I sign-in the users (we don't use okta's sign-in page):

```js
const oktaClient = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);
const oktaData = await oktaClient.signInWithCredentials({ username, password });
```

Any thoughts if it is bad if those issuerId and cliendId are exposed or is that normal?

Comment: If their examples have these keys in the client it should be fine. Typically, private keys will be labelled as such and should not be exposed

Comment: `ISSUER` and `CLIENT_ID` don't sound very much like authentication credentials to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issuer and client ID are public information. I like to think of a client ID like a vehicle's license plate. It's just an identifier and doesn't contain any private information. Client secrets are the only thing you need to worry about. They should never be in any frontend code.

Comment: but given the issuer and client ID, then they can create some kind of script that runs `signInWithCredentials` or whatever methods in oktaAuth, then they can try to brute force the credentials? I was thinking along those lines...

Comment: Okta’s rate limiting should prevent this.